# We treat interfaces and implementations like we treat content and styling, so why not handle it similarly?

Tags: language-agnostic, dependency-injection, aop

I've used Spring, and I've looked into Guice, and I think that these are both rather obtrusive extensions to languages. I firmly believe that programming languages themselves need to adapt to patterns more cohesive to dependency injection, testing, etc., so why not gravitate to a stylesheet based approach? By allowing multiple "stylings," you could define configurations of objects for different purposes. Perhaps classes and other goodness could allow you to specify ranges of transactions more powerful than simple class/method name matching.

Does this seem like a good idea to anyone? Also, do you think that DI and AOP will be integrated into future languages as a core feature, rather than an afterthought? I was just thinking, and seems like interface -> implementation corresponds almost exactly to data -> style.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a very old idea, first implemented in the early 1980s.  Then it was known by the terms "configuration programming", "software integrated circuits" or "architecture description languages".  "Dependency Injection" is a neologism coined when enterprise developers recently rediscovered the ideas.

For examples, look at the Conic [1] and Regis/Darwin [2] systems.  These systems were used to write industrial control software and directly influenced how software is** written for Phillips' TV sets. An interesting feature of [Darwin](http://www-dse.doc.ic.ac.uk/Research/Darwin/) is that the language has both a textual and graphical representation [3] and a [formal semantics](http://pubs.doc.ic.ac.uk/DarwinPiCalculus/).

Conic and Regis/Darwin did a lot more than existing DI frameworks because they were used to construct distributed systems: the configuration language compiled into a program that deployed the system in parallel across a network of machines (the formal semantics define how this "elaboration" process operates).  In comparison, Spring, Guice etc. only configure objects within a single address space and leave the much greater difficulties of connecting distributed components up to the programmer.

Another rediscovery of the idea is the [TinyOS](http://www.tinyos.net/) operating system for sensor net applications, although that does not have as clean a conceptual model of components and configuration.

1. Kramer, J., Magee, J., Sloman, M.S., and Lister, A., CONIC: An Integrated Approach to Distributed Computer Control Systems, IEE Proceedings., 130, Pt. E, ( 1983), 1-10.
2. Magee, J., Dulay, N. and Kramer, J., Regis: A constructive development environment for distributed programs, Distributed Systems Engineering Journal, Vol. 1, No. 5., Sept 1994, 304-312
3. Kramer, J., Magee, J., and Ng, K., Graphical Configuration Programming, IEEE Computer, 22(10), (1989), 53-65.

** maybe "was" by now.

Comment: Wow... I think that's the first time I've seen someone include formal citations in an SO answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find electronic versions of the papers online, or I would have linked to them directly.